# ResolutionFailedException occurs randomly with no configuration change

Tags: .net, wcf, unity-container, enterprise-library

I have a WCF service that is using the Unity block.

The dependencies are resolved using a service locator pattern.

This service receives several requests a second, during mainly business hours. The app pool hosting it hosts no other processes and recycles at 2am each day.

Since installation, we've seen this error occur three times (early January, early February, today) so it's very intermittent.

The exception we get is:

```
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, ServiceContracts.IAuthService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
```

This is resolved by calling `.Resolve<T>` on the Unity container. The container is static and is configured the first time it is called by

```
    _unityContainer = New Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer()
    _unityContainer.AddNewExtension(Of Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Interception)()
    _unityContainer.AddNewExtension(Of Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Unity.EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension)()

    _unityContainer.LoadConfiguration()
```

I don't believe there is anything wrong with the configuration as this is happening at only one install site (service is installed in other locations without issue).

Unity version is `2.0.414.0`.

Unity Configuration occurs thru web.config, such as:

```
<unity>
    <container>
        <register type="ServiceContracts.IAuthService, ServiceContracts" mapTo="ServiceContracts.AuthService, ServiceImp" />
    </container>
</unity>
```

**Update to add**

Each service implementation has two ctors - one with no parameters, the other with param injection which is used for testing. The param-less ctor is called by WCF contains a call to the helper class (`Unity`) which is a very thin wrapper over the Unity container, and implements a service locator pattern.

So for the class wrapping the described IAuthService, the ctor looks like this:

```
private IAuthService _authService;

public AuthWrapper()
{
    _authService = Unity.Resolve<IAuthService>();
}
```

The Unity helper class which is in VB.NET looks like this:

```
Public NotInheritable Class Unity

    Private Shared _unityContainer As IUnityContainer

    Public Shared Function Resolve(Of T)() As T
        If _unityContainer Is Nothing Then Call configure()
        Return _unityContainer.Resolve(Of T)()
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub configure()
        _unityContainer = New Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer()   
        _unityContainer.LoadConfiguration()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Can you show more info (and code) about when `LoadConfiguration` is called?  e.g. what file and method does it reside it?

Comment: @RandyLevy I'll add it to the original question, give me 5 minutes to type it out.

Comment: Thanks for updating your code.  Your code is definitely not thread safe so the first thing I would do is to fix that.  Looks like you want a singleton (using shared functions) but you are not preventing multiple threads from accessing the shared _unityContainer.  If using .NET 4+ you could use a [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode.aspx) to initialize container in a thread safe matter.  If not then you can adapt one of the other singleton approaches at: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx .

Comment: @RandyLevy How is this not thread safe? The container is loaded at startup, reads from the container don't need to be locked as it's not being modified?

Answer (score 0):

`InvalidOperationException` -- this indicates that the interface is not registered in the container.

Why could that be happening?  If the `LoadConfiguration` is only called once at startup it would seem that either the registration is lost in the container (I've never seen that before) or the container has been created but `LoadConfiguration` not called yet.  The latter seems more likely. Perhaps the app pool has shut down/recycled (timeout?) and then two requests come in at the same time.  It's possible (can't be certain since the posted code is not complete) that there is a race condition during bootstrapping.

e.g. request #1 comes in and the container is created.  At the same time request #2 comes in, finds the container created and attempts to resolve.  However request #2's resolve occurs before request #1 has finished loading the container configuration.  That scenario explains the described behavior however, without more information, it's not clear whether that is what is actually happening in this case.

Comment: Hi, @RandyLevy, I've added more information to the post. Your explanation could make sense but we've subjected this service to very heavy load and have never seen this before in our testing. Also, if the race request was right, then you'd assume that following requests would have the container populated.